# How to make Butterfly Shuffle in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, shuffle

How to make numbers for butterfly shuffle in java script.

```
Input = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;

Result = 9,7,5,3,1,0,2,4,6,8;
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Put in some effort my friend, try it yourself and then ask when you get stuck - don't ask us to do it for you

Comment: 1. filter, 2. sort/reverse, 3. concat

Comment: @N.Jadhav I do not think so

Comment: Try using `map` - `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map( (s,i,arr) => i < arr.length/2 ? arr[arr.length - i*2 - 1] : arr[((i-1)*2 - arr.length) + 2 ] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```js
var a = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
var arr = a.split(',');
var arrA = [];
var arrB = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  arrA.push(arr[i]);
}
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  arrB.push(arr[i]);
}
arrA.reverse();
var res = arrA.concat(arrB);
res.reverse();
console.log(res.toString());
```